# Type 'string[]' which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. - How do I deserialize the json string?

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I have below `json`

```
 "PayloadData": {
      "CustomFields": ['test','test2'],
      "SampleNumber":"123"
     }
```

I am using below code to deserialize the json.

```
   Message message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(payloadData);
```

Here is my property in `Message` class

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets CustomFields
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [DataMember(Name = "CustomFields")]
    public List<string> CustomFields{ get; set; }
```

But, I get below error.

> "The property 'Message.CustomFields' could not be mapped, because it is of type 'string[]' which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'."

Comment: That sounds like an Entity Framework error to me, which suggests you've used this `Message` class in your `DbContext` and *that's* where the error is occurring. You can't map `List<string>` to a database column. It's nothing to do with JSON serialisation.

Comment: Can you add the code for the `Message` class? Also can you try making `Message.CustomFields` a `List<string>`?

Comment: @PatrickHollweck yes it's List<string>

Comment: @CharlesMager  Yes, I am using entity framework.

Comment: I agree with you @CharlesMager.  since I can't map List<string> to a database column, how do I fix this? shall i concatenate all values with ";" and store as string in database?  or one more table with foreign key reference of collection of items?

Comment: By the way, you meant "Json.NET", right? Not "jsonnet"?

Comment: yes, Json.NET :)

Comment: See https://forums.asp.net/t/2096921.aspx?list+string+is+not+a+supported+primitive+type+or+a+valid+entity+type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using this [online json to C# class generator](http://json2csharp.com/) to get the structure of a POCO required to deserialize a json string.

Then simply map it to your EF class (using AutoMapper for example):

So for this JSON:

```
 {
  "CustomFields": ['test','test2'],
  "SampleNumber":"123"
 }
```

this is the POCO that is generated:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<string> CustomFields { get; set; }
    public string SampleNumber { get; set; }
}
```

if this is your actual JSON:

```
    { "PayloadData":     
     {
      "CustomFields": ['test','test2'],
      "SampleNumber":"123"
     }
    }
```

this is how your POCO is supposed to look like:

```
public class PayloadData
{
    public List<string> CustomFields { get; set; }
    public string SampleNumber { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public PayloadData PayloadData { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I am using entity framework and It's nothing to do with JSON serialization. Now, I am wondering how to store this list in database!

Comment: your payload data is a json string? Right? then you are trying to deserialize it into an EF code first class? If so, i am suggesting to first deserialize it to a POCO then map it to which ever EF class you require.

Comment: @kudlatiger List or Array is not supported as a column type in the SQL database. You need make it as a separate class so it will be a separate table in the database. Let's say CustomField class with ID and Field properties, then update the Message class's CustomFields prop to be list of CustomField type.